# Patch 1.5.0 Arcade and new 'Total Career Games' statistic - what exactly does it count?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to know what exactly counts towards "Total Career Games" in StarCraft II.
Does it count co-op and custom games, or only quick-match games? Does it include FFA as well?

Comment: I don't think "total career games" is new, and I also don't think it counts anything but league games.

Comment: From the Path 1.5.0 release notes: "New statistics have been added to the Player Profile: Games Played This Season, Most Played Mode, and Total Career games."

Comment: I would put this into an answer but I have no source nor do I have a exact answer. But, I'm 99% sure its all games you have ever played, custom, FFA, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this post](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/5070667580) that had the following to say:

> **Total Career Games**
>
> Instead of showing total wins, it now shows total career games, as the community requested. You guys didnt want to
>   see just half the info by only getting to know the wins, but you
>   wanted to see the total matches played. So once again -> This is a big
>   plus you guys asked for!

The number is the amount of league games played(Including FFA). Based on my own numbers I can say this does not include co-op, vs AI or custom games.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering the way I know it includes FFA is because I went and tested it :)